# Airflow metric of a queued task

Tags: airflow, datadog

Currently our Airflow metrics are sent to Datadog with https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/airflow/?tab=host. There's a metric airflow.executor.queued_tasks: the number of queued tasks on executor, but I'm looking for the queued task name. Any idea of how to get it?

More context: I would like to get an alert if a task has been queued for more than X minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can try another airflow-exporter: https://github.com/epoch8/airflow-exporter. With this exporter, you can get the status of each DAG (including "queue" status)